# GitHub pages site re-directing to custom domain instead of index.html

Tags: html, github, github-pages

This is my 2nd question so far. I am making a file share site on git hub with a basic pages domain. To get to it, i type: [minegamer5570.github.io/Filehub/](http://minegamer5570.github.io/Filehub/), It goes to the home page. I just started using GitHub pages when i inserted a custom domain and later realise you have to buy the domain to use it. So i went back to the basic pages domain and now when i add index.html onto the link, It goes to the custom domain and not the home page. Can anyone please help?

("minegamer5570.github.io/Filehub/index.html" goes to "filehub.io/index.html" which does not exist.)

Comment: It doesn't redirect me. You probably just have that redirect cached somewhere. Try reloading with ctrl-f5 and flushing the DNS cache (http://www.redsome.com/flush-clear-dns-cache-google-chrome-browser/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must clear your cache. My first visit to

"minegamer5570.github.io/Filehub/index.html"

has no redirect